# When should we redeploy .war file in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm currently deploying the MobileFirst project .wlapp, .adapter and .war file.

How frequent should I redeploy .war file? I just want to clarify this sentence from [this document](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/moving-production/moving-development-environment-stand-alone-qa-production-servers/),

> The client configuration files are in the apps\your-app folder.

Which files are they referring to? Is it these 2 files only:

1) application-descriptor.xml

2) build-settings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .war file contains the authenticationConfig.xml and any libs and server Java code. Basically everything that is in the server folder of your MobileFirst project.

If you change anything there and expect it to be available in your production server, you need to re-deploy the re-generated .war file (it gets regenerated on each and every change made to files in the server folder).

Comment: Hi Idan Adar, I do understand that i need to re-deploy the .war file if I change the server folder...What about "apps" folder?

Comment: From the apps folder you get your generated native projects that after you build those (in Xocde, Android Studio, etc...) you get the app files that you upload to the app stores. You also get in the bin\ foldrer the wlapp files and adapter files that you upload to the server (via the console or via ant scripts). These are not related to the .war file.

Comment: The document contradicts your explanation. Quoted from the document "The client configuration files are in the apps\your-app folder." "All the files that are mentioned above are compiled to the project-name.war file in the \bin folder of the project."

Comment: I wrote that document. The wlapp files do not go to the .war files.

Comment: It is also written: "The only exceptions are apps and adapters, which are not part of the WAR file."